# Neo4j Return a node only if where clause is always true

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, cypher, nodes

Consider the following Neo4j Database example:

**Nodes are (Basket) (Booking) and [:IS_BOOKED_IN]**

Now Booking looks like this: **Booking {start: number, end: number}**

If you book something you choose which basket you want to book it with and the relationship [:IS_BOOKED_IN] gets created between those two.

*This works perfectly fine.*

Now I want to check on my next booking if ANY basket is available for the timeframe that I select.

Right now I'm doing this in Cypher with this query:

> **MATCH (basket:Basket)-[:IS_BOOKED_IN]->(booking:Booking)
>   WHERE ({start} < booking.start AND {end} < booking.start) 
>   OR ({end} > booking.end AND {start} > booking.end) 
>   RETURN basket**

*{start} and {end} are numbers*

As you can see this will  work as expected, but only if there is just one booking. As soon as there are more bookings I will get the same basket back, even though it is obviously not available, thus making my query useless.

This happens because the query doesn't stop when the WHERE clause fails, instead it takes the same Basket node again and checks the other bookings, which don't fail and in turn give me back the basket..

**How can I change this, how can I tell Neo4j to only return the basket to me if the WHERE clause is always true? Or just skip the basket if it fails just once..**

Any ideas appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a collection, i.e. `collect` and then the `ALL` predicate.

```
MATCH (basket:Basket)-[:IS_BOOKED_IN]->(booking:Booking) 
WITH basket, collect(booking) as bookings
WHERE ALL(booking in bookings WHERE
       ({start} < booking.start AND {end} < booking.start) 
    OR ({end} > booking.end AND {start} > booking.end))
RETURN basket
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That was exactly what I needed, perfect solution for my problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for CASE expression [see Neo4j documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/milestone/cypher-expressions.html#syntax-simple-case)

Case can be used to return the result only if it meets your requirements.

Example:

```
MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.name = "foo"
RETURN CASE when u.age > 18 THEN u ELSE null END as result
```

Another solution can be to change "OR" for "AND" in your WHERE clause, then the result will be taken only if the two conditions are met.

Comment: Didn't know about the CASE expression, unfortunately it didn't help me with my problem, thank you for trying though, learned something anyway :)